# Footer at the bottom of the page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to keep the footer at the bottom of the page even when the content of the page is not very high. When the user makes the page smaller and the foot meets the content, the scroll should appear and footer should hide below the content.

(I don't want the footer to be in fixed position, because when it meets the content, the footer would be at the top and hide the content)

There is a very good example of James Taylor suggested here by Philippe. I want the same effect but with jQuery. (I cannot apply this css solution because I need the content to be in absolute positioning) http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm

```
$(function(){   
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();
    if(documentHeight >= 420){
        $('#foot').css({position: 'absolute',bottom:'10px'});
    }

    else{
        $('#foot').css({position: 'absolute',top:'410px'});
    }   
})
```

Comment: Do you realize you don't have jQuery selected in the fiddle? If I do so, things work fine as soon as I scroll. That said, `display: flex` would work great if it was supported everywhere: http://jsfiddle.net/2AWeV/.

Comment: I updated to select the jQuery. Thank you. I think I did not explain well. I don't want flex. As Philippe says: I want to keep footer at bottom of the window even if body is smaller than the window, but if body is greater, footer will be at bottom of the document. The solution of Philippe with css is ok. But I still don't understand why my solution with jQuery doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. Why do I have a negative point? If I knew the problem I would solve it!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
var topDistance = $('#foot').offset().top;
```

[edit]

if you want to keep your footer on the page, always at the bottom , you'll need to use

```
position: fixed; 
bottom: 10px;
```

But if you want to keep footer at bottom of the window even if body is smaller than the window, but if body is greater, footer will be at bottom of the document

Here is the a solution : http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: The solution with css is very good. Thank you. But it has some limitations, I think it is not possible in my context. The solution with jQuery seems really good but it doesn't seem to work. Do anybody know why? put it in practice here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdAsn/43/